# Switching 13.5VAC

Tags: ac, switching

Would a relay that's meant for mains AC work for 13.5VAC? If not, what type of component/circuit would be best suited for this application? This is meant for a door buzzer/opener that functions on 13.5VAC. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the coil, or switching the voltage on the contacts?

Comment: Which part of the relay ist designed for mains AC? Solenoid or contacts? I assume the solenoid. If so, you can safely test without risking any damage.

Answer (score 0):

If the coil is designed for 120/240VAC, it probably won't work if driven with 13.5VAC.  If you're driving the coil as specified and the contacts are rated for 120/240VAC, they'll switch a 13.5VAC signal without any problem.

Comment: The relay I'm thinking of is driven by 5VDC for switching 120/240VAC.

Comment: please add this information to your question